# excel assemble two sheets exported from database

Tags: database, excel, vba

I have two sheet of excel exported from a database with hundreds of rows. 
In first sheet I've these columns

```
name  age  gender
id1    23    m
id2    45    f
```

In second sheet these columns

```
id1 john smith
id2 jean ford
```

I'm looking for a macro or somethig else to automatically replace the idx in first sheet with the corresponding values from second sheet.

The final result should be a sheet like:

```
name         age  gender
john smith   23     m
jean ford    45     f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything as complicated as a macro-- [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) will suffice:

> Searches for a value in the first column of a table array and returns
>   a value in the same row from another column in the table array.
>
> The V in VLOOKUP stands for vertical. Use VLOOKUP instead of HLOOKUP
>   when your comparison values are located in a column to the left of the
>   data that you want to find.

For example, if your id-sheet mapping was on `Sheet2`, then the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2.$A$1:$B$2, 2)
```

would look for the value found in this sheet's `A2` cell in the leftmost column of the data table located in `Sheet2.$A$1:$B$2`, and then return the value from the 2nd column of that table.  Copy that downwards, and get something like

[image: example snapshot of sheet]

Comment: is quite perfect, =VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$24; 2).

Comment: is quite perfect, =VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$24; 2), now the problem is that in my second sheet data is store in few columns john in first column and smith in second column so the formula retrieve only john. I don't know if I've to concatenate all the column in second sheet into only one or vlookup formula can do also this.

Comment: You can do the concatenation wherever you prefer.  Either `=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(..., 2), " ", VLOOKUP(..., 3))` or concatenate them yourself and then do one lookup.